# How to join one table with another two tables in sql?

Tags: sql

Suppose I have 3 tables and want to join three tables as Result below without repetitive values and NOT NULL.

```
Table-1: EMP
Id   Name  Client_Id
1    abc    c1
2    xyz    c2
3    pqr    c3
```

Table-2: EMP_Account:

```
Id    salary
1     10,000
2     20,000
3     30,000
```

Table-3: Client_Details;

```
Client_Id   Client_Name
c1              client_1
c2              client_2
c3              client_3
```

Final Result:

```
Id  Name    Salary  Client_Name
1   abc     10,000     client_1
2   xyz     20,000     client_2
3   pqr     30,000     client_3
```

I tried to do Join with Left join but not success.
So, can anyone help me or suggest that how we can do this?

Comment: Please add what you have tried

Answer (score 2):

You can join more than once, but each must be in its own section

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.salary, t3.client_name
from EMP t1
inner join EMP_Account t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
inner join Client_Details t3
  on t1.client_id = t3.client_id
```

Aliasing helps

If you want to return results even where there is no client info, substitute `inner` for `left`

Comment: Is it work with NOT NULL values and without repetitive values ?

Comment: @Jay If you have duplicates, use `select distinct`. And yes, works with `not null`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, ea.salary, cd.client_name
FROM emp e
JOIN emp_account ea ON e.id = ea.id
JOIN client_details cd ON cd.client_id = e.client_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT E.ID, E.NAME, EA.SALARY, CD.CLIENT_NAME FROM EMP E
JOIN EMP_ACCOUNT EA ON EA.ID = E.ID
JOIN CLIENT_DETAILS CD ON CD.CLIENT_ID = E.CLIENT_ID
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.